# What's the correct word to replace 'antiness' or 'againstness' in the following context?

Tags: word-request

> "Antigen is a substance that causes **'antiness'**."

another one

> "They always in the side of '**antiness**'."

I'm looking for a word (noun) that means '**state of being anti**' (anti=against) for something, something like '**antiness**' or '**againstness**' (if something like that would exist... I mean, these two words don't really exist but they absolutely can give an hint for what I'm looking for.)

---

Editing: the word againstness exists in English. My mistake. (thanks to Malik)

Comment: *anti* meaning "against everything"? I don't know who would use *anti* this way. Are these actual examples you found somewhere? There is some such usage, like here - [*anti*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anti_1) but I have never heard such phrasing used.

Comment: @user3169 Although it's not used this way in English, I suspect some other languages actually do form this word using their equivalents of _anti-_ and _-ness_. If that's the case, the question is a very good fit for the word request tag.

Comment: @user3169 I didn't write that anti means "against everything", or something like that.

Comment: If you don't want people to guess at what you mean, you should add what "anti" means in your context, along with relevant examples. And don't use a word to define the same word (or a form of it).

Comment: Fair enough! I added some words.  Did they make it more understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you said it!

Againstness is **the word** for that. I also see that it has been made popular recently (20th century!)

Here you go:

> *[againstness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/againstness)* - The state or condition of **being against or in opposition** to an established view, etc.

See the origin of the word!

Comment: Thank you! I don't why I didn't check before if this word exists, but  anyway I thought about it a long later after I wrote the question and then I added it by editing.

Answer (score 2):

For the examples you've given, the best word would probably be *opposition*. There are certainly other options in some contexts, including rewording the sentence.

Comment: @Intrigued_by_proliferation I have to apologize; that was a bit of sloppy scholarship on my part. Almost that whole paragraph was wrong; since it's not needed to answer the question as asked, I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

"Reaction" is fairly close to both of the original post's requests.  For example:

> An antigen is a substance that causes an immune reaction.
>
> They are reactionaries.

(In politics, [reactionaries](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reactionary) "react" to changes by trying to go back to the way they imagine things were before the changes.)

In physics (and other fields subject to conservation laws):

> Every action is associated with an equal and opposite reaction.